# Is there a way to notify whenever tweet list is updated in twitter embedded widget?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am using twitter embed widget on my website. It posts twitter timeline on my page. I want to toast whenever the tweet list gets updated.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="382" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#2B7BB9" data-chrome="nofooter " href="https://twitter.com/Arushi_Rajput?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Arushi_Rajput</a>

<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

List gets updated itself through twitter widget so if I post a tweet on my timeline it automatically updates the list after 30 seconds on my page.

I want to toast whenever I receive a new tweet.

Comment: What do you mean by toast? Do you need any alert? Also can you share the url or   code that you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 window.onload= function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("twitter-widget-0");
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document)y = y.document;
    y.getElementsByClassName("timeline-TweetList")[0].addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
        alert("New Tweet Received!!");
    });
  };
```

It has been some time while I posted this question. This is the code that worked!

Comment: That is good, but you may describe what you did to improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using DOM subtree events...Like below,

```
$('.your-instaposts-container-class').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
  alert('New post Added or Your new post html');
});
```

Comment: its not working as expected. Initially when the page loads its shows the alert when it should not and secondly after I posted a tweet on my timeline, the list got updated but not the alert

Comment: Can you share your live url, so that i can properly look into that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/arushirajput/pen/mQmKqX I have created this pen however I need to tweet for you to test as I am using my own timeline. If you want to tweet and check you can go to https://publish.twitter.com/# and choose option profile and edit it with your username and generate your embed and tweet and test

Comment: I think you need to manipulate this domsubtreemodified event as per your requirements, This will surely help you if you use it with setTimeout for preventing first time alert for the added posts.

Comment: ohk i will prevent first somehow but, alert does not occur afterwards where it is required

Comment: I checked it too... the alert is arriving multiple times for every tweet I suppose.